# Javascript: Split string by loop in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, split

I've got string with IDs and Names separated by ^ (between ID and Names) and ; (between sets)  for example

```
var string = "1^John Smith;2^Sophia Williams;3^Emily Johnson;";
```

I need to get something like this

```
$('#1').html('<option value="1">John Smith</option><option value="2">Sophia Williams</option><option value="3">Emily Johnson</option>');
```

I tried loops but got stuck:

```
var string = "1^John Smith;2^Sophia Williams;3^Emily Johnson;";

var a = string.split(";"),
    i;
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  if (a[i] !== ""){
    var b = a[i].split("^"),
    i2;
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < b.length; i++) {
      var name = b[i2];
      console.log(name);
    }
  }
}
```

Im not sure that it's good way

Comment: You don't need the inner loop at all. Just construct the string using `b[0]` and `b[1]` where needed.

Comment: Side note: jQuery tolerates it, but `#1` is an invalid selector. An ID selector cannot start with an unescaped digit.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Option()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)

> `new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected)`

```js
var string = "1^John Smith;2^Sophia Williams;3^Emily Johnson;"

var options = string.split(';').map(i => {
  return new Option(...i.split('^').reverse())
})

$('#1').html(options)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="1"></select>
```

Comment: Even though it appears to work in the version of jQuery used in your answer, I'd be nervous about relying on passing an array of `Option`s to `html`, it doesn't seem to be [documented](https://api.jquery.com/html/) behavior.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It does look very hacky to do `new Option(...i.split('^').reverse())` I am not even sure how it works with the ...

Comment: @mplungjan - That part isn't a problem: It splits the string `i` at `^` (getting, for instance, `["1", "John Smith"]`) and then reverses that array and spreads it out as two arguments to the `Option` constructor (text and value). :-)

Comment: Ah. Because the array works  - I was not able to console.log(...i.split('^').reverse()) in a way that I could trust that new Option would like it

Answer (score 1):

You can build a HTML string inside your loop by grabbing the first element from `b` as the value for your option and the second element from `b` to be the text in your option tag. You can then add a string HTML version of the option tag using these text and value components to the accumulated string each iteration of your for-loop:

```js
var string = "1^John Smith;2^Sophia Williams;3^Emily Johnson;";

var a = string.split(";");
var html_str = "";
for (var i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) { // loop to a.length-1 so you don't need an if-statement to check blanks
  var b = a[i].split("^");
  var val = b[0];
  var txt = b[1];
  html_str += '<option value="' + val +'">' + txt +'</option>';
}

$('#one').html(html_str);
console.log(html_str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="one"></select>
```

An alternative approach could be to use a regular expression to get the components from your string an convert it to your desired HTML string by using `.replace()` with a replacement function:

```js
var string = "1^John Smith;2^Sophia Williams;3^Emily Johnson;";
var html_str = string.replace(/(\d+)\^([^;]+);/g, (_, val, txt) => `<option value="${val}">${txt}</option>`);

$('#one').html(html_str);
console.log(html_str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="one">
</select>
```

The above regular expression:

- `(\d+)\^`: Groups any digits (group 1) which have a carat `^` following them
- `([^;]+);`: Groups any characters which are not a semi-colon `;` (group 2), which are followed by a semi-colon.

These groups are formed for each occurrence in your string, and then used in the `.replace()` method's callback, where group 1 is `val` and group 2 is `txt`.